# A Better Way to Load a Javascript Slider

Tags: jquery

Ok, maybe I've been going about this the wrong way. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction as to what I should be Googling to accomplish either loading the second and third images in my slider only after the page has fully loaded. Another option would be not to load anything in the div containing the slider at all until the page has fully loaded and the images within that div have fully loaded. I tried LazyLoad for the slider images before, but it only conflicted with the slider's 'slide left' effect http://varmag.com/ . Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently needed a way of preloading images. I was about to use a few  lines of javascript code but came across a cool way of doing so by using CSS :). Here is the link: http://perishablepress.com/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/
Isn't it cool? So simple.

Comment: The thing about that is the file still loads. What I want to do is save load time